# How to generate a batch file with msfvenom?

Tags: msfvenom

How do you generate a batch file for windows `.bat` using msfvenom, msfvenom does not seem to have a batch file like format and is it possible to convert a `.ps1` to `.bat` file

Answer (score 1):

A `.ps1` file is a PowerShell script: unlike `.bat` and `.cmd` it's executed in Windows PowerShell instead of the Windows `cmd.exe`. While it's possible to "convert" a PowerShell script into a batch script that calls PowerShell, the requirement for the PowerShell framework remains.

If that's what you are looking for, for a longer script like the one produced by msfvenom, I'd suggest the method explained in Dmitry Sotnikov's [PowerShell script in a .bat file](https://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2008/06/27/powershell-script-in-a-bat-file/):

1. Put the code inside curly brackets and assign it to a variable.

   ```
   $code = {
       # code here
   }
   ```
2. Base64 encode it with PowerShell:

   ```
   [convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($code))
   ```
3. Use it in your batch script with `powershell.exe -EncodedCommand`